# Powers Shell issue while connecting to SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Anyone can help here please:

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Users\chauda31\SharePointDLL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type –Path "C:\Users\chauda31\SharePointDLL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


#Mysite URL
$site = 'https://triasdasdadcaplc.sharepoint.com/sites/ServadfficeDeliveryDashboard/'

#Admin User Principal Name
$admin = 'arvind.chaudhary@cedsfsfcxznt.com'

#Get Password as secure String
$password = Read-Host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString

#Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Daily Status')
$context.Load($list)
#$list.Description = "CSOM PowerShell - Did it!!!"
$list.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials]: verify that
>   the assembly containing this type is loaded. At
>   C:\Users\chauda31\OneDrive - Centrica\Documents\SharePointPS.ps1:18
>   char:16
>   + ... edentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCr ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Anyone can help here please

Comment: It seems that there are issues while loading the assemblies. Can you check if the path of the two dll is correct?

Comment: Yeah i checked , dll are corrects

Comment: Have you tried loading them in a different way? Like using `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile`  . You can give a look to [this](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-resolve-issues-when-loading-dlls-in-powershell/) blog, maybe you can get closer to the solution.